# Audiocontext Web Audio API createMediaStreamDestination().stream no audio

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

I am trying to receive audio from the microphone and pass it through some filters and create a stream again from it and sent it to speakers so that I can listen to the processed audio.
But when I pass the new stream to the destination I can't hear any audio.

```
const [stream] = await Promise.all([
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
        deviceId: { exact: input.value },
        channelCount: { ideal: 1 },
        noiseSuppression: { ideal: false },
        echoCancellation: { ideal: true },
        autoGainControl: { ideal: false },
        sampleRate: { ideal: 48000 },
    },
  }),
]);
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
//filters will be added later
//source.connect(context.destination) this works i can hear the audio
const newStream = context.createMediaStreamDestination().stream;
//I need to convert the filtered audio back to stream
const source2 = context.createMediaStreamSource(newStream);
source2.connect(context.destination); //this doesnt work i cant hear audio
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code misses the connection from your original `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` (called `source` in your code) to the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` (which isn't assigned to a variable yet).

If you change your code like this it should work:

```
const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
const newStream = destination.stream;

source.connect(destination);
```

But I think you don't need the second stream if you only want to listen to the processed audio. Let's say your effect is a `GainNode`. I know this is not the most spectacular effect out there but I hope it's good enough as an example. You could connect your source to that `GainNode` and then connect the output of the `GainNode` to the destination of the `AudioContext`.

```
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
const effect = context.createGain();

// This modifies the gain so we can hear a difference.
effect.gain.value = 0.5;

source.connect(effect);
effect.connect(context.destination);
```